# Subjectivity in combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

I found some questions in combinatorics very subjective for example:

> With the digits $1,2,3,4,5,6$, how many 4-uplas exists (order matters)
>   where the digit 1 is before 4?

The solution of this question in my book is $72$, I found $107$ as a solution because:

$$1\cdot1\cdot6\cdot 6=36\ \text{(14 in the first two positions as 1456)}$$

$$6\cdot1\cdot1\cdot 6=36\ \text{(14 in the middle as 5146)}$$

$$6\cdot6\cdot1\cdot 1=36\ \text{(14 in the last two positions as 5614)}$$

So we remove one 4-upla because the one $1414$ is in the first and third subsets abouve, then the solution is $36\cdot 3-1=108-1=107.$

The solution in my book is wrong or I misinterpreted this question?

How do we deal with these kind of subjective combinatorics questions? (what the author means by $1$ before $4$? he implicitly said we have to remove the 4-uplas with $4$ before $1$? he means $1,4$ *together* as $1456$ or it can be separated as 1546?)

I think these kind of question are common in combinatorics at least in high school combinatorics questions.

Thanks

Comment: That's not really subjective so much as 'poorly written.' For what it's worth I'd read 'before' as not requiring adjacency, since you could denote that case by "must contain the string 14."

Comment: Note as well that this case is not as bad as it could be: the cases with 1&4 adjacent are a special case of 1 being earlier than 4. So you at least can tell which set will be bigger. (In other cases, poorly written problems could leave that uncertain.)

Comment: I would argue that there is very little issue with the terminology "comes before", since a tuple has a natural ordering.  In a poset with order $\leq$, the phrase "$a$ comes before $b$" is synonymous with $a \leq b$.  The only thing implicit in the question is that you're actually making ordered selections from the set $\{1, \dots, 6\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is indeed under-specified, and the wording can be interpreted in several different ways. It is plausible that the problem-setter intends us to count the $4$-digit numbers, where the digits are distinct, are chosen from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, include a $1$ and a $4$, and have the $1$ appearing somewhere before the $4$, but not necessarily immediately before.

The "other"  digits can be chosen in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways. Then the $4$ digits can be arranged in $4!$ ways. In half of these ways, the $1$ comes before the $4$, for a total of $\frac{\binom{4}{2}4!}{2}$.

We obtained $72$. But there are other interpretations, which mostly will yield other answers.